# agile transformation and its affect on release management

Tags: agile, release-management

Can anyone give me some insight in what happens to traditional release management when an entire enterprise moves into agile?

for example, lets say an enterprise operates in a waterfall method, does one big release a month and the systems are tightly integrated.

lets say the enterprise moves to agile and the dev teams get restructured to operate in agile. Now that the teams are operating on sprints and developing features each sprint, how does the release management team have to change to support the agile teams working in sprints now?

Comment: If a large enterprise of tightly integrated systems is able to do major releases on a monthly basis, why would you change anything?

Answer (score 3):

Agile doesn't necessarily have any affect at all on release management. Agile is about how you build the software. How you deploy it is (or can be) completely unrelated. At the end of the day (or week, or month, or quarter, or year) your teams deliver software, and you deploy.

If you're big enough to have a dedicated release management team, their work can stay the same. They wait for engineers to deliver working software, and then they deploy it.

That being said, once your organization matures its agile practices, you may find that you have smaller, more frequent deliverable chunks of data to be deployed. When that happens, your release management team will need to be prepared to release more often.

Comment: so what about when multiple teams are leveraging systems that tied together...they would still have to release at the same time then?

Comment: @user2061886: what do you do now? My guess is, you wait to release until all of the software has been integrated together. That doesn't change just because the teams are using agile. Just because a team has finished a sprint and has potentially shippable code doesn't mean you _have_ to ship it.